# Getting ID of clicked element using strict type

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Let us assume we want to log the ID attribute of a clicked element with the following TypeScript code:

```
onClick(event) {
  console.log(event.target.attributes.id.nodeValue);
}
```

The above function receives the clicked object as a parameter, but the type in this case is `any`. If I check the result of `typeof event` I get `object`. So I would modify my code as follows:

```
onClick(event: object) {
  console.log(event.target.attributes.id.nodeValue);
}
```

In this case, I receive an error in VS Code as below:

[image: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)]

So what is up with this? Using the type `any` as parameter type works, the console logs the desired ID without any error, but if I decide to use a strict `object` as parameter type, my code does not compile. Where is the issue?

The affected HTML code is the following;

```
<h1 id="foo" (click)="onClick($event)">...</h1>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I've added an HTML example at the end of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I check the result of `typeof event` I get `object`.

That's runtime code, so it's the JavaScript `typeof` operator, which says `"object"` for **all** objects (and `null`).

> So I would modify my code as follows...I receive an error is VS Code like below

Plain objects don't have a `target` property.

The type of the event object for a `click` event is [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). (You've tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [angular](/questions/tagged/angular). If you're using jQuery or the DOM to attach the event, it'll be the DOM's `MouseEvent`. If you're using Angular to attach the event, [it looks like](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts#handling-events) it'll also be the DOM's `MouseEvent`. Caveat: I don't use Angular.) You'd also probably want `event.currentTarget.id` or `event.target.id` rather than using the `attributes` collection and `nodeValue`, since the `id` attribute is a reflected property.

**But**, the DOM's `MouseEvent` interface inherits its `currentTarget` property from [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), which just defines it as an `EventTarget`. You know that it will be an `Element`, but unfortunately the interface just says it's `EventTarget`. (The same is true for `target`.)

As far as I'm aware, there's no predefined interface for a `MouseEvent` that defines `currentTarget` as `Element` instead. You can reliably (in this situation) use a type assertion:

```
onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log((event.target as Element).id); // Or `(event.currentTarget as Element).id`
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgwgGxhA1gCgKYBueYUAXIgLJwgDOeAokSQJSIDeAsAFCK+IQIacNHgB0aOAHMc+JlFFQAhgCdJeKIkU1E9EQFtiUZqJgATZgG5uffoOFiJ02YdEQQy5YYAqKtRq06+obGZpbcAL7cQA)

I don't like type assertions, but they are sometimes necessary.

Sometimes you see people doing that same assertion slightly differently, like this:

```
onClick({target}: {target: Element}) {
    console.log(target.id);
}
// or
onClick({currentTarget}: {currentTarget: Element}) {
    console.log(currentTarget.id);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgwgGxhA1gRgBQDeUAhgE4DmAplAL4BciRZVUDAompQLaVi0CUjALAAoROMQQEAZzicAdGjjk8JCtXkwAJvwDcomqNCRYCZGHSYsAJkIQQpUrygAVZtXqN7j52-WtEDm5nGkECUQlJGTlKRWU8byc+PxZNHX0RQxEgA)

You might create a reusable type instead, like this:

```
interface ElementMouseEvent extends MouseEvent {
    currentTarget: Element;
    target: Element;
}
```

...and then use it (which is still making an assertion, but again, a safe one):

```
onClick(event: ElementMouseEvent) {
    console.log(event.target.id); // Or `event.currentTarget.id`
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsIFsLgLID2ArgM4SoBuuYyEAHpCACYnKGnlXjIDeAsACgAkAiJQo1ACpwoAcwhgAXGkw5wAbkFCwM+UpXZqmgQF9BgmERAIwwAiGT2AwumAIA1gAoIXfRkP4xGSU1ACUvILIUcgI9iQEmAB06ASy3r6JOnIKicBMocbRMXEJEMmp6dSJouJSujl5BYJmAkA)

If you want to go *fully* typesafe, you could have a type assertion function that throws a clear runtime error if the assertion is invalid:

```typescript
function assertIsElement(obj: object | null): asserts obj is Element {
    if (!(obj instanceof Element)) {
        throw new Error(`Object is not an Element instance`);
    }
}
// ...
onClick({currentTarget}: MouseEvent) {
    assertIsElement(currentTarget);
    console.log(currentTarget.id);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoElUCiANhgLYZhQAUcARgFYBcid9G0iAPomCEUQEpmaTDlQsGiGOOJkKURAG8AsAChEGqcERUAhDUkwwqKMkgY422eUoCBStZqeIoACyxwA7jwzeCWDywqAAMAeQZ2BWkeOAUzRGt5KWNTc2CBAG5HTQBfNTzVAHpCxAA6crVQSFgEFjAAYSIYCABrKkUIEAD5ABVkLABzDCgc5gBZOBBMAgA3eXsVdU0RbDxCEhtqTu7KPsHhzOyNCARUOBJSojgBqm2sXv6hqFKYABND1RygA)

If you control where `onClick` is used (e.g., you know you're using it on an `Element`), that may be overkill.

Comment: If I change the type to `MouseEvent`, the `event.currentTarget.id` returns two errors. First, _Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)_, second, _Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)_. I am using jQuery with Angular, which is based on TypeScript, so it's kind of a complicated matter.

Comment: @Viktor - I forget that the DOM event objects only define the targets as `EventTarget`, not as `Element` (since they also target `Document` for instance). I'm used to the React synthetic event types, which are generic (`MouseEvent<Element>`). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I still don't understand why there is not a proper way of just getting an id... I might be too ignorant. xD

Comment: @MMatthieu - Most of the options above are "proper." I've just added one that's fully typesafe, though in most cases that would be overkill.